# Sending a variable from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I know I have asked this question before, but I am having trouble understanding the answers I get. I have the following code in two separate files, one of them javascript and the other php:

Javascript

```
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
       document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getgames.php?yearFilter="+yearFilter,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
```

php

```
$yearFilter = (int)$_REQUEST["yearFilter"];
$dummyvariable = 123245;
```

I have been using the javascript file to pass variables to php but I cannot figure out how to send a variable (such as the dummyvariable example) from php BACK to the javascript file. I know that result should end up in "this.responseText" but I don't know what code to put in the php file in order to send it there. I keep being told to "echo" the variable to javascript but whenever I try all I am seeing is the variable being printed to the screen, I am not seeing any evidence that it is being STORED in javascript. What am I missing?

Comment: `echo $dummyvariable;` should just work. Since you are making an HTTP request to execute the script, the output will be returned in the HTTP response.

Comment: You can define a variable and store the value there(instead of showing it using innerHTML). What is the problem?

Comment: Look at using jQuery, it's a lot simpler to use for Ajax requests.

Comment: jquery's Ajax is your friend. You can access success and error handlers inside an Ajax call

Comment: @FelixKling and what if he want more than one value

Comment: @litelite: Then he encodes an array as JSON.

Comment: @Styphon: There is nothing wrong with the OP's Ajax code here, so using jQuery won't magically make it work.

Comment: @messerbill the problem is not there

Comment: @FelixKling No, but it's easier to use the error function built in to jQuery Ajax for debugging.

Comment: @Styphon: Maybe. Personally I don't find it particularly difficult to add `if (this.readyState === 4) { console.log(this.status, this.responseText); }`, or better, use the Network tab in the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply output the varible value like this

```
$dummyvariable = 123245;
echo $dummyvariable;
```

so now in javascript

```
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=this.responseText;
```

this line will add 123245 into #dummy id

if you want to send multiple variable values into javascript simply response with json

like that

```
$dummyArray = json_encode(array("var1"=>"x1","var2"=>"x2"));
echo $dummyArray;
```

now in javascript use this line code

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

in this case now response contain values of var1 and var2 ...
here is how to use

```
alert(response.var1); // this will return x1;
alert(response.var2); // this will return x2;
```

Comment: So once I've added the line 123245 to #dummy id, how do I access it?

Comment: simply you can access it by this this.responseText 
create variable for this just like that
var data = this.responseText;

now you can use data any where which containing value 123245 from php

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the help.  Unfortunately, I still seem to be missing something essential.  That is, all the answers tell me to use "echo" in php which just writes whatever I try to pass back on the screen.

I tried both of your versions.  For the second one I get:

{"var1":"x1","var2":"x2"}

on my screen.

How can php distinguish an echo statement that writes to the screen from one that just "passes" the variable to the browser?

Comment: @user5237344 Php echo statement is just writes an output its not passing variables to browser.. Echo only use to print text or html in browser.. So we are just using this output in JavaScript to further process ... Its not actually passing variables and about my second example m just using php json_encode function for converting array to json string if you don't know what is json you should learn.. And in js m using JSON.parse function to conventing json string into javascript object which we printed in php using echo .. So echo is just for outputting something its not use to pass variables

Comment: Its up to you what to do with output ...in this case we using output to create variables for further process in JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it in the response text.

```
echo $dummyvariable
```

Remember, what php does is just build a file that will be sent to the browser. Aside from that file no other information is sent to the browser.

Also, i would recommend encoding it in JSON (See Zebi Rajpot answert)